# Como aplicar o "goto" no quicksort? (c, c++)

Tags: c, c++, classificação, quicksort

Estou realizando um trabalho para minha faculdade onde pede que um algortimo quicksort seja feito em C, utilizando o "goto" o máximo que puder.

No código abaixo eu apliquei o "goto" até onde meu conhecimento permite, porém gostaria que alguem me ajudasse a aplicar o "goto" no resto do algoritmo.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void quickSort(int *vetor, int inicio, int fim)
{

int i, j, meio, aux;

init0:

i = inicio;
j = fim;
meio = vetor[(inicio + fim) / 2];

init1:

if (i <= j) {

init2:  
if(vetor[i] < meio){
i++;
goto init2;
}

init3:  
if(vetor[j] > meio){
j--;
goto init3;
}

if(i <= j)
{
aux = vetor[i];
vetor[i] = vetor[j];
vetor[j] = aux;
i++;
j--;
}

goto init1;

}

if(inicio < j) {
quickSort(vetor, inicio, j);
}

if(i < fim){
//quickSort(vetor, i, fim);
inicio=i;
goto init0;
}

}

int main(){

int arr1[10] = { 55, 44, 32, 11, 68, 97, 92, 30, 62, 74 };
int pivot, j, e, i, aux;

i=0;
j=9;

quickSort(arr1, i, j);

i=0;
inicio3:
if (i<10) {
printf("%d ,", arr1[i]);
i++;
goto inicio3;
}

}
```

Comment: Eu odeio esses requisitos. Além dele não servir pra nada, não ensinar algo útil, ele depende de interpretação. Quando parar de usar o `goto`? Dá pra você sair enfiando `goto` onde não é estritamente necessário, mas pra que? Eu acho que está bom assim. Na verdade é um código horroroso, mas não é culpa sua, pelo menos em parte.

Comment: Sim, eu também de certa forma acho desnecessário, porém é uma atividade que me foi solicitada. não sei se o professor vai achar o meu código suficiente. Suspeito que ele queira que eu substitue a função pelo "goto" também.

Answer (score 2):

O `goto` é um pulo não condicional, pode ser considerado base pra todo *controle de fluxo*.

Com uma combinação de `if` e `goto` você pode criar qualquer controle de fluxo, creio que esse é o objetivo do peculiar exercício.

Embora seu código já esteja reduzido a `if`s. Recomendo que você escreva o código de *maneira normal* e depois substitua os controles de fluxo por construções usando `goto` (caso não tenha sido assim que resolveu), como nos exemplos:

**if / else**

```
if(x==0)
{
    printf("verdadeiro\n");
}
else
{
    printf("falso\n");
}
printf("fim if else\n");
```

Pode ser representado com `goto`s:

```
if(x==0)
    goto if_1; //se o if for verdadeiro, executa essa expressão
    goto else_1; //se for falso, ignora a expressão anterior e executa essa

if_1:
    printf("verdadeiro\n");
    goto fim_if_else1;

else_1:
    printf("falso\n");
    goto fim_if_else1;

fim_if_else_1:
    printf("fim if else\n");
```

**for**

Dados:

```
int a=0;
int b=5;
int x;
```

O loop:

```
for(x=a; x<b; x++)
{
    printf("{for entre [%d e %d)} x = %d,  \n", a, b, x);
}
printf("fim [for]\n");
```

Pode ser explicitado usando `goto`s:

```
inicio_for_1:
    x=0;
verifica_for_1:
    if(x<b) 
        goto corpo_for_1;
        goto fim_for_1;
corpo_for_1:
    printf("{for entre [%d e %d)} x = %d,  \n", a, b, x);
incremento_for_1:
    x++;
    goto verifica_for_1;
fim_for_1:
    printf("fim [for]\n");
```

**do...while**

O código

```
int x = 5;
do
{
    x--;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
while(x>0);
printf("fim do{...}while(...)\n");
```

pode ser representado assim:

```
inicio_dowhile_1:
    int x=5;
corpo_dowhile_1:
    x--;
    printf("%d\n", x);
verifica_dowhile_1:
    if(x>0)
        goto corpo_dowhile_1;
fim_dowhile_1:
    printf("fim do{...}while(...)\n");
```

**Chamada de função**

O C requer a função `main`, onde o programa inicia. Outras funções podem ser codificada dentro dessa, e os argumentos podem ser declarados como variáveis locais. Você estará emulando uma chamada de função e passagem de parâmetros:

```
int func1(int x, int y)
{
    return x*y;
}

int main(void)
{
    int r = func1(4,5);
    printf("%d", r);
}
```

Pode ser representado assim:

```
int main(void)
{
    //espaço para declarar todas variáveis necessárias
    int func1_argx;
    int func1_argy;
    int func1_resultado;
    int r;

    //equivalente a chamar função:
        func1_argx = 4; //define primeiro argumento
        func1_argy = 5; //define segundo argumento
        goto func1_interna; //~chama função~
    ponto_retorno:  //nomeia ponto de retorno

    //resto do código da main
        r = func1_resultado;
        printf("%d", r);

    goto main_final; //vai para o final do main, ignorando código da função

    //parte reservada para função:
    func1_interna:
        func1_resultado = func1_argx*func1_argy;
        goto ponto_retorno;

    main_final: ;
}
```

---

Além de substituir os controladores de fluxo, você pode fazer um código tão complexo e confuso quanto queira, dando origem ao que se chama de *código spaghetti*, mas não creio que seu professor está querendo algo assim...

Essa resposta tem fins didáticos, procure compreender a equivalência das construções =)

Talvez seu curso vá para linguagens de baixo nível depois... Em nível de hardware os controles de execução são implementados por testes em registradores e pulos, algo diretamente relacionado a `if`s e `goto`s.